# Parse rows in a column to list each unigram, bigram, and trigram in excel

Tags: excel, vba

As title states, I'd like to parse each row in a table(1 column, ~1k rows) using a space as deliminator. Each row contains a short phrase. I want to list all unigrams, bigrams, and trigrams for each phrase. Example data and desired output format below.

`the quick brown fox       the          the quick       the quick brown
jumps over the lazy dog    quick        quick brown     quick brown fox
                           brown        brown fox       jumps over the
                           fox          jumps over      over the lazy
                           jumps        over the        the lazy dog
                           over         the lazy
                           the          lazy dog
                           lazy
                           dog`

Comment: You can use `Split(phrase," ")` to separate the words into an array, then a For loop with appropriate Step parameter to loop over the array and list out your n-grams.  *Try something*, then post back with code if you run into problems.

Comment: Apologies for not including previous methods. I have previously used text to columns to get each individual word, and then concatenate to put them together. After a few rows it got daunting, to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your different sentences are in the first column

```
Sub splitIt()

Dim vArray As Variant

Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

Dim SentenceRange As Range

Dim startRowB, startRowC, startRowD As Long

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set SentenceRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1))

startRowB = 1
startRowC = 1
startRowD = 1

For Each Cell In SentenceRange

    vArray = Split(Cell.Value, " ")

        For y = 0 To 2
            For x = 0 To (UBound(vArray) - y)

                If y = 0 Then
                    Cells(startRowB + x, 2).Value = vArray(x)

                ElseIf y = 1 Then
                    Cells(startRowC + x, 3).Value = vArray(x) & " " & vArray(x + 1)

                ElseIf y = 2 Then
                    Cells(startRowD + x, 4).Value = vArray(x) & " " & vArray(x + 1) & " " & vArray(x + 2)

                Else

                End If
            Next x
        Next y

    startRowB = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    startRowC = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    startRowD = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Next Cell


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This ran great for a sample set of data. When I apply it to a larger sample set I get a Run-time error '1004' when this runs after a few moments :(

Comment: which version of excel are you using? I know 2003 has an issue with array sizes? At what line in the code did you see the error? I'm useing 2013 not having any problems running the code. what's the longest sentence you have?

Comment: @Angrypirate and how many rows of data trying to see if I can recreate the error

Comment: I am using 2013 as well. I would receive the error when it would parse line 22370 or so. The error would occur when listing the data in column D. I think it was an error on my end when I typed up the module for the larger dataset, I started over and viola. Success.

Comment: awesome glad it worked. I was trying to break it on my end with no luck

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example for the single cell **A1**

```
Sub grams()
    Dim K As Long, i As Long
    K = 2
    ary = Split(Range("A1").Value, " ")

    For Each a In ary
        Cells(K, 1).Value = a
        K = K + 1
    Next a

    K = 2
    For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary) - 1
        Cells(K, 2).Value = ary(i) & " " & ary(i + 1)
        K = K + 1
    Next i

    K = 2
    For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary) - 2
        Cells(K, 3).Value = ary(i) & " " & ary(i + 1) & " " & ary(i + 2)
        K = K + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

You would adapt the same scheme for multiple cells.

Comment: Thank you for your example. This will be a great chance for me to become more knowledgeable in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Antother approach

```
Sub getIt()

X = Split(Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))), vbNewLine), vbNewLine, Chr(32) & "|"), Chr(32))
[b1].Resize(UBound(X) + 1) = Application.Transpose(X)
[c1].Resize(UBound(X)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEFT(R[1]C[-1],1)<>""|"",RC[-1]&"" "" &R[1]C[-1],"""")"
[d1].Resize(UBound(X) - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(LEFT(R[1]C[-2],1)<>""|"",LEFT(R[2]C[-2],1)<>""|""),RC[-2]&"" "" &R[1]C[-2]&"" ""&R[2]C[-2],"""")"
[c1].Resize(UBound(X) + 1, 2).Value = [c1].Resize(UBound(X) + 1, 2).Value

With [b1].Resize(UBound(X) + 1, 3)
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlUp
.Replace "|", vbNullString
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You never cease to amaze me.